# Beautiful Soup Extract first TD

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from a HTML table using beautiful soup.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import webbrowser
import httplib2

import pyodbc 
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint

quote_page = 'https://ph.investing.com/economic-calendar/'

table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'id': 'economicCalendarData'})

req = urllib.request.Request(quote_page,headers={'User-Agent':"Magic Browser"})
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = resp.read()
html = data.decode('ISO-8859-1')
#print(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
print (soup.prettify())

table = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'id': 'economicCalendarData'})
print(table)

res = []
for tr in table:
td = tr.find_all('td') 
if row: 
    res.append(row)
print (res)
```

But the first TD that the table has it the date.

```
https://ph.investing.com/economic-calendar/
```

[image]

I want to save that date in a variable, then take the rest of the data into a table

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
df
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow` community, please edit your question and include the `HTML` source as a `code`, check [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use to following css selector to get the table first column value of date.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'}
r=requests.get("https://ph.investing.com/economic-calendar/",headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
table=soup.find('table',attrs={"id":"economicCalendarData"})
print(table.select_one('tbody>tr>td.theDay').text)
```

Or you can use.

```
 print(soup.select_one('table#economicCalendarData>tbody>tr>td.theDay').text)
```

OR

```
  print(soup.select_one('table#economicCalendarData td.theDay').text)
```

---

To print entire table on data frame and import into csv.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'}
r=requests.get("https://ph.investing.com/economic-calendar/",headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
print(soup.select_one('table#economicCalendarData td.theDay').text)
table=soup.find('table',attrs={"id":"economicCalendarData"})
df=pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df1=df.iloc[1:,:7]
print(df1)
df1.to_csv("index.csv", index=False)

**Output**:



   Friday, April 3, 2020
     Time Cur. Imp.  ...   Actual Forecast Previous
     Time Cur. Imp.  ...   Actual Forecast Previous
1   05:00  KRW  NaN  ...  400.21B      NaN  409.17B
2   05:30  AUD  NaN  ...     37.9      NaN     42.7
3   06:00  AUD  NaN  ...     38.5     39.8     49.0
4   08:01  EUR  NaN  ...     32.5      NaN     59.9
5   08:30  AUD  NaN  ...     0.5%     0.4%    -0.3%
6   08:30  JPY  NaN  ...     33.8     32.7     46.8
7   08:30  HKD  NaN  ...     34.9      NaN     33.1
8   09:45  CNY  NaN  ...     43.0      NaN     26.5
9   13:00  SGD  NaN  ...    -8.6%      NaN    -5.3%
10  13:00  SGD  NaN  ...    -8.9%      NaN     0.2%
11  14:30  SEK  NaN  ...     46.9      NaN     56.4
12  14:45  EUR  NaN  ...   -35.2B      NaN   -20.0B
13  15:00  EUR  NaN  ...    -1.3%     2.1%    -2.2%
14  15:15  EUR  NaN  ...     23.0     25.5     52.1
15  15:15  ZAR  NaN  ...     44.5      NaN     48.4
16  15:30  THB  NaN  ...    34.4B      NaN    35.1B
17  15:30  THB  NaN  ...   227.2B      NaN   219.9B
18  15:45  EUR  NaN  ...     20.2      NaN     50.7
19  15:45  EUR  NaN  ...     17.4     22.0     52.1
20  15:50  EUR  NaN  ...     28.9     30.2     52.0
21  15:50  EUR  NaN  ...     27.4     29.0     52.5
22  15:55  EUR  NaN  ...     35.0     36.8     50.7
23  15:55  EUR  NaN  ...     31.7     34.3     52.5
24  16:00  EUR  NaN  ...    -2.4%      NaN     2.2%
25  16:00  NOK  NaN  ...   10.70%   13.50%    2.30%
26  16:00  EUR  NaN  ...     29.7     31.4     51.6
27  16:00  EUR  NaN  ...     26.4     28.4     52.6
28  16:30  GBP  NaN  ...     36.0     36.2     53.0
29  16:30  GBP  NaN  ...     34.5     34.8     53.2
30  17:00  NOK  NaN  ...    1.50%      NaN    3.60%
31  17:00  EUR  NaN  ...     0.9%     0.1%     0.7%
32  17:00  EUR  NaN  ...     3.0%     1.7%     2.2%
33  19:30  INR  NaN  ...  475.56B      NaN  475.56B
34  20:30  USD  NaN  ...     3.1%     3.0%     3.0%
35  20:30  USD  NaN  ...     0.4%     0.2%     0.3%
36  20:30  USD  NaN  ...     34.2     34.1     34.4
37  20:30  USD  NaN  ...    12.0K      NaN    33.0K
38  20:30  USD  NaN  ...     -18K     -20K      13K
39  20:30  USD  NaN  ...    -701K    -100K     275K
40  20:30  USD  NaN  ...    62.7%    63.3%    63.4%
41  20:30  USD  NaN  ...    -713K    -163K     242K
42  20:30  USD  NaN  ...     8.7%      NaN     7.0%
43  20:30  USD  NaN  ...     4.4%     3.8%     3.5%
44  21:00  BRL  NaN  ...     37.6      NaN     50.9
45  21:00  BRL  NaN  ...     34.5      NaN     50.4
46  21:00  SGD  NaN  ...     45.4      NaN     48.7
47  21:45  USD  NaN  ...      NaN     40.5     49.6
48  21:45  USD  NaN  ...      NaN     39.1     49.4
49  22:00  USD  NaN  ...      NaN     45.0     57.8
50  22:00  USD  NaN  ...      NaN      NaN     55.6
51  22:00  USD  NaN  ...      NaN      NaN     63.1
52  22:00  USD  NaN  ...      NaN     44.0     57.3
53  22:00  USD  NaN  ...      NaN      NaN     50.8
```

Comment: have you read `I want to save that date in a variable, then take the rest of the data into a table`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη : He might have updated later.However you have provided some wrong output :-p

Comment: i will review it later. :P

Comment: I will review these later and let you know. Very kind.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozila'}

r = requests.get(
    "https://ph.investing.com/economic-calendar/", headers=headers)

df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={'id': 'economicCalendarData'})[0]

date = df.iloc[0][0]

print(date)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

```
Friday, April 3, 2020
```

**data.csv** [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/40999310cc6a07fe6002507dcfba15d5/data.csv)

[image]